# Sound crackling – Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio

I have sound disturbances: A quiet crackling in the background and a loud hissing / crackling when I start Firefox, for example.

The problem occurs only when playing through the speakers –
the speakers are connected directly via AUX and are powered via USB. 
The speakers are not the problem;
these disturbances do not occur under Windows.

**What I've tried so far**

1. in config: `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

   - Added `tsched=0` to the line `load-module module-udev-detect` && `pulseaudio -k`
   - Commented out the following line: `load-module module-suspend-on-idle` && `pulseaudio -k`
2. in config `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`:

   - Set Pulse `default-sample-rate` to `48000` && `pulseaudio -k`
3. `killall pulseaudio`
4. Unplugged the speakers and plugged them in again

**System information:**

- Linux system 5.15.0-33-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 13:34:26 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- ii  pulseaudio   1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1   amd64   PulseAudio sound server

Comment: For diagnosing that sort of problem, always bypass any sound server. Start from raw alsa playing your file with *aplay*. (giving the parameters according to the characteristics of your sound file and the output you desire if not in accordance with alsa default settings)

Comment: @MC68020 Unfortunately, I'm not really familiar with this and don't quite know what you mean. I haven't changed anything in the sound settings and packages - this is the default configuration. I'm not trying to play a special "sound file" either. It's about sound disturbances in normal system operation / IDLE.

Comment: Start disabling any sort of USB related power saving settings. And also if you can find another system to be used only for supplying the power via its USB.

Answer (score 1):

On my system this seems to have been caused by the volume change deferred volume setting in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`.  When I set `enabled-deferred-volume = no` and made sure my lines for `default-sample-rate` and `alternate-sample-rate` were commented out, my crackling went away after I rebooted pulseaudio `pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio --start`

Edit: the issue ended up returning when I slept and unslept my system.  I'm not sure why but the sample rate changed from 44100Hz to 48000Hz when my system restarted and when it was at 48000Hz the crackling came back.  So I uncommented the default-sample-rate and set it to 44100.  My headphones show up in several different output modes so to see which sample mode was working with and without the crackling I checked `pacmd list-sinks | grep "sample spec" -B 12` which showed "state: RUNNING" on the one I wanted to check and the sample spec for the output frequency at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried many ways but ultimately found the solution like this:

ı have installed `alsamixer`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install alsa-utils
```

Then open alsamixer by `alsamixer` command. The screen will open in the terminal.
click `f6` and select your device, then scroll right via the right arrow and come to Auto-mute mode. You can follow it by checking the `item` option above.
you need to enable it by pressing the `up arrow` key. Eventually, it will suddenly stop popping sound. I wish you good work :)

Answer (score 0):

Playback was pausing intermittently so I dropped default-sample-rate to 20000 (arbitrarily)in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf and it seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: You may have accidentally plugged the USB into a USB 1 port (rare though, usually 1.1 is used), 16 bit 44.1 khz audio runs at around 1.4 megabit/s, but usb 1.0 is also around 1.5 mb/s (1.1 is 12 mb/s), which could be why you saw the audio artifacts vanish at 20khz sampling rate. Or it's a bad cable, but USB 2 or greater should handle standard CD quality 44.1/16 bit audio fine, USB 2 runs at around 480 mb/s roughly. Note that dropping the sampling rate is going to lead to other audio artifacts since your effective audio is now only 10khz or less, rather than the standard 20khz.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in my desktop setup, a lot of intermittent but then persistent hissing and crackling. Rebooting helped about 50% of the time, and sometimes restarting pulseaudio. Finally figured out that system grounding was my problem. I had inadvertently created a ground loop between the system housing, UPS, and sound system (Logitech subwoofer).

Answer (score 0):

On my end I have never been able to fix the problem for good. These days, when this happens, I just do:

```shell
pulseaudio -k
```

And launch again whatever audio source was playing. Every single time, the sound is clean up to the next sleep or reboot.
Not a real solution but I hope it helps some.